# Call Photoshop CS5's "auto color" (shift+ctrl+B) from script?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script, photoshop-cs5

Is there any way to run Photoshop CS5's "auto color" function (Image->Auto Color, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) from a script written in Javascript? Looking at the "Adobe Photoshop CS5 Javascript Scripting Reference", I see `autoLevels()` and `autoContrast()`, but no `autoColor()`. I tried calling `autoColor()` anyway in the hope it might have just been accidentally omitted from the documentation, but no luck. :-(

If there's no function to call directly from a script, does the Photoshop scripting API have some way to simulate pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (to fire off something that exists in a menu, but doesn't support directly calling from a script)?

If there's no direct access to something like `ActiveLayer.autoColor()`, and no way to kludge a simulated keystroke to fire off a function, can you at least have a script that's iterating through multiple files load one, do everything that can be automated, pause so I can press <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> to do the auto-color, then resume execution of the script to save it as a JPEG & close the original .dng file?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var idLvls = charIDToTypeID( "Lvls" );
    var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idautoBlackWhite = stringIDToTypeID( "autoBlackWhite" );
    desc.putBoolean( idautoBlackWhite, true );
    var idautoNeutrals = stringIDToTypeID( "autoNeutrals" );
    desc.putBoolean( idautoNeutrals, true );
executeAction( idLvls, desc, DialogModes.NO );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always add custom (not available in api) steps to a script by creating an action in the actions pallet then running it from within the script:

```
doAction("action name", "action set");
```